# What is the trend for RTSP, RTMP vs. HTTP progressive download regarding HTML5 video?

Tags: video-streaming, html5-video

We are looking into HTML5 video to deliver interactive video experiences such as **controlling the video via hyperlinks** (e.g. allowing the user to jump to portions of the video which have not been downloaded yet) as well as **JavaScript responding to events from the video** (e.g. something happening when video reaches 00:25).

For test videos this seems to be possible with libraries such as Video.js and delivers a decent experience in the modern browsers.

I am reading a text from 2009 which seems to indicate that soon (perhaps today), that modern browsers will catch up to and surpass the features of streaming protocols and servers:

> *RTSP has been created for video communications analogous to voice-over-IP applications. It is not the best protocol for on-demand streaming, where HTTP with byte range requests achieves the same result. Extra functionality that RTSP supports is also increasingly available with HTTP progressive download approaches. Only the live communication case is one that may require a RTP/RTSP implementation over UDP to work with the required low latency.*
>
> *RTSP-like streaming approaches that require special server and client software have increasingly failed in an HTTP dominated world. For example, YouTube is entirely provided through HTTP progressive download and does not use RTMP. In this situation, vendors have embraced HTTP progressive download and developed their own feature extensions to improve HTTP-based streaming.*

**What future do streaming protocols such as RTSP/RTMP and video streaming servers such as Adobe Streaming Server have when seen in the light of the increasing features that browsers are adding to support HTML5 video?**

Answer (score 1):

Adaptive bitrate streaming on HTTP is still under discussion (DASH) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Adaptive_Streaming_over_HTTP

Adobe streaming server, Apple have edge till DASH becomes reality. Content protection is another area (DRM) is not finalized for HTTP streaming.